# Ionic build ios error code 65

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

While trying to build ios using `ionic cordova build ios`, I am getting the following error -

> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/raihan/Downloads/quitch-app/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Quitch.xcworkspace,-scheme,Quitch,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/raihan/Downloads/quitch-app/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/raihan/Downloads/quitch-app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

I have searched through the net since a long time but can not find any solution.

**My plugins list**

```
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.1.10 "PhotoViewer"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.19 "File Opener2"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.23 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player 1.0.6 "CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.4 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

**My system info**

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.2 (/Users/raihan/Downloads/quitch-app/node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova)
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1 (/Users/raihan/Downloads/quitch-app/node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular)
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.6.0 (/Users/raihan/Downloads/quitch-app/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils)
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.6.0 (/Users/raihan/Downloads/quitch-app/node_modules/ionic)
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.0.2
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.5.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.11.3
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
ios-sim           : 6.1.2
npm               : 5.3.0
```

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the errors. The issues are as follows -

1. The main problem was with the `cordova-plugin-console` plugin. Cordova do not support this plugin since `cordova version-ios 4.5.0`.
2. Also I had to provide the updated `google-json` file.

Now it is building successfully on XCode and Emulator.